# Lua timing thread

Tags: multithreading, lua

How do I write a thread, or a co-routine (correct my nomenclature) to execute one function in Lua while the mainline code looks at its results and makes decisions ?

What I want is a function, something like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
--   Countdown_Nine_Seconds()                            --
--                                                       --
--   On Entry:  Nothing                                  --
--                                                       --
--   Returns:   Nothing                                  --
--                                                       --
--   Action:    Decrements these two counters...         --
--                                                       --
--              Full_Wait                                --
--              Tenth_Wait                               --
-----------------------------------------------------------

  function Countdown_Ten_Seconds()

  Full_Wait = 9                             -- This will be a global
  local i
  local j

  for i = 9, 0, -1
    do                                      -- This is the I loop start
     Tenth_Wait = 10                        -- ten tenths in a second
      for j = 10, 0, -1
       do                                   -- This is the J loop start
        box.wait(100)                       -- our implementation has this; wait 0.1 seconds
         Tenth_Wait = Tenth_Wait - 1        -- Tell the rest of the world
          end                               -- end of inner J-Loop
           Full_Wait = Full_Wait - 1        -- One less second
            end                             -- end of ouer I-Loop
             end                            -- end of this complete function
```

I would then like to have a main line code do something like

```
  While(Full_Wait > 0)
     do
     :
     :
     :
     (my stuff here)
     :
     :
     :
     :
     end
```

What's the syntax ? Where do I read about this ?

What else am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lua co-routines are collaboratively threaded. They need to explicitly yield control to one another. They don't run at the same time.

If you need preemptive threading you need one of the various lua threading libraries.

Comment: Okay, what, when, where, how ?, or could I let `CountDown` yield after he counts down each tenth of a second ? If so, how do I do that ?

Comment: Yes, you could absolutely have your countdown function yield after each loop and have the caller check the result. I'm not sure if that's going to get you the behaviour you want though but it might. I believe the lua-users.org wiki has a few threading libraries listed. I imagine github does as well. Google may find a few more also. The lua mailing list has had discussions about them in the past also.

Comment: Thanks. Cancel my plans. Better to know this now than later.